# How do I use pexpect to run things in the background?

Tags: python, ssh, pexpect

I am using the `'Pexpect'` library in a script and wanted to do some operations after that. What I am doing is as follows:

```
def child():
        pexpect.spawn("ssh tranzmeo@192.168.21.110")
        child.expect(".*password.*")
        child.sendline('tranzmeo1@#')
        print(child.before)
        child.interact()
        return
```

This is a function I call from another file (which I call training.) When I run training, the `child()` is called, but immediately it stops the program and enters into the `tranzmeo` console, which I don't want. I need to `ssh` into it and do some operations in the background in tranzmeo. How can I do that using pexpect?

My `operation` is as follows(just for your reference):

```
def scp(tensorflow_file_location_temp ,tensorflow_file_loc)
        child = pexpect.spawn("scp -r " + tensorflow_file_location_temp + "models@192.168.21.117:" + tensorflow_file_location )
        child.expect(".*password.*")
        child.sendline('Tranzmeo1@#')
        child.interact()
```

Comment: If the environment allows you to, you can create a ssh key, scp it to the host and allow authentication without password. This should remove the need of trying to feed the password (which sits in plain text) to the ssh process.

Comment: I have other operations as well,not only  scp!

Comment: Well you can simply run other commands with ssh. Usage: 

ssh <username>@<ip> <command>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.interact()` [gives control of the child process to the interactive user (the human at the keyboard). Keystrokes are sent to the child process, and the stdout and stderr output of the child process is printed.](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.spawn.interact)

If you don't want that, don't call it! You want to continue working with the object returned from `pexpect.spawn("ssh tranzmeo@192.168.21.110")` (the code you posted doesn't assign that to `child`, which I assume is a copy-paste error):

```
child.sendline("scp -r " + tensorflow_file_location_temp + "models@192.168.21.117:" + tensorflow_file_location)
```

But you ought to set up ssh keys, then you'll be able to do what you want without passwords and `pexpect` altogether by [simply running `scp`](https://superuser.com/questions/686394/scp-between-two-remote-hosts-from-my-third-pc).

Comment: Hi , I understand that scp can be done by a child.sendline,but what if I need to do some functions that involve other operations?

Comment: I'm not sure what other problems you are facing. Here you asked why you're getting dropped into the remote console, the answer is that's happening because of the call to `interact`. Perhaps a separate question with more details on what you're trying to do is in order..